# Average of irrational flow on the torus

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, irrational-numbers, ergodic-theory

Let $$F(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi y)}}$$
defined on $\mathbb{T}^2$. Here $\mathbb{T}^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/ \mathbb{Z}^2$ is the 2-torus. How can I show that
$$ \lim_{T\longrightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T F(x,\sqrt{2}x)\;dx = \iint_{[0,1]^2} F(x,y)\;dxdy?$$
What can we say about the rate of convergence? Say $\frac{1}{T^\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Can you kindly define $\mathbb{T}^2$? More details means a bigger probability to get an answer.

Comment: I just did it, it is simply integration over the unit square!

Answer (score 1):

In the original version of the question $F$ was continuous.

This is true for any continuous $F$. First do it for $$F(x,y)=e^{2\pi i(nx+my)},$$for $n,m\in\Bbb Z$. So it holds for $F$ equal to a trigonometric polynomial. Now show the property is preserved under uniform limits...

Of course that no longer works, at least not so simply, with the current version of $F$. One might approximate $F$ from below by continuous functions and try to estimate the error at the fairly mild singularity.

**Edit:** I believe it's true. Don't have time to try to write a formal proof, but I can explain sort of why I believe it:

The crucial thing is that $$\lim_{\delta\to0}\int_{-\delta}^\delta|t|^{-1/2}\,dt=0.$$

Notation: Let's write $$\int F=\int_0^1\int_0^1 F(x,y)\,dxdy$$and $$I_F(T)=\frac1T\int_0^TF(x,\sqrt 2x)\,dx.$$ For $\lambda>0$ let $$F_\lambda=\min(F,\lambda).$$Then $$\lim_{T\to\infty}I_{F_\lambda}(T)=\int F_\lambda,$$since $F_\lambda$ is continuous. So  if we can show that $$I_{F_\lambda}(T)\to I_F(T)$$*uniformly* for $T>0$ as $\lambda\to\infty$ we're done. And it seems to me that this convergence is in fact uniform in $T$, because for any positive integer $n$ the integral $$\int_{n/\sqrt2}^{(n+1)/\sqrt2}(F(x,\sqrt 2x)-F_\lambda(x,\sqrt 2x))\,dx$$is zero except for maybe one or two singularities no worse than $\int_{-\delta}^\delta|t|^{-1/2}\,dt$, where $\delta\to0$ as $\lambda\to\infty$.

Comment: The problem is $F$ has a singularity, can you explain more, and we obtain a rate?

Comment: Actually it is true for all $F$ Riemann integrable, which is necessarily bounded. In this case clearly $F$ is unbounded.

Comment: Since $2 - \sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi y) \geq 2 - 1 - 1 = 0$, your function $F$ is at least continuous (although not necessarily $C^\infty$) on all of $\mathbb{T}^2$, and as such is a uniform limit of trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: It has a zero at $(1/4,1/4)$, note that it is 1 divides by $2-\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi y)$. Thus $F$ blows up at this point.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong question, I just fixed it!

Comment: Do we have a rate?